# How could i automatically update my api documentation in readme.io?

Tags: api, documentation, auto-update, readme.io

I want to update my rails API documentation automatically in readme.io. Can anyone guide me about any tool or process which I should use

Answer (score 0):

You should use their CLI to trigger an update every time you make a change in your documentation repository.

https://github.com/readmeio/rdme